# Detecting Key presses for Special Characters

Tags: java, jbutton, keylistener

I am trying to change the background color of buttons when a key with the same letter/symbol is pressed but the problem is this code is not working for symbols and Space, What am I doing wrong and how can it be fixed?

Here is the code:

```
    private String names[]={"`"," 1 "," 2 "," 3 "," 4 "," 5 "," 6 "," 7 "," 8 "," 9 "," 0 "," - "," + ","  Backspace  "
        ,"  Tab  "," Q "," W "," E "," R "," T "," Y "," U "," I "," O "," P "," [ "," ] "," \\ "
        ,"  Caps Lock "," A "," S "," D "," F "," G "," H "," J "," K "," L "," ; "," ' ","  Enter  "
        ,"  Shift  "," Z "," X "," C "," V "," B "," N "," M "," , "," . "," / "," ^ "
        ,"                             "," < "," ! "," > "};


public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event)
    {
        int code= event.getKeyCode();
        String x;

        for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
        {

            s=names[i];
            x=s.trim();

            if(x.contentEquals(event.getKeyText(code)) )
            {
                backColor=but[i].getBackground();
                but[i].setBackground(Color.RED);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event)
    {
        String x;
        int code= event.getKeyCode();

        for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
        {
            s=names[i];
            x=s.trim();

            if(x.contentEquals(event.getKeyText(code)))
            {System.out.println("outside");
                but[i].setBackground(backColor);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at you `names` array and compare that with the results of `KeyEvent#getKeyText`

My little test program outputted this...

```
[PRESSED ] "Space"
[TYPED   ] "Unknown keyCode: 0x0"
[RELEASED] "Space"
[PRESSED ] "Enter"
[TYPED   ] "Unknown keyCode: 0x0"
[RELEASED] "Enter"
```

You're `names` array has space stored as `" Space "`, which is never going to match.

You should never rely on the results from `KeyEvent#getKetText` as it does not take into account the current extended state of the keyboard (ie if shift is pressed) which may change the state of the key.

For example, if I type ['], my test program will output `Quote`, but if I type [shift+'] (which should produce ["]) it still says `Quote`.  Don't even get me started on { and [ :P

If you're not interested in display the text of the key stroke, you're better off relying on the virtual key value

```
public class PaintMyKeys {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new    PaintMyKeys();
    }

    public PaintMyKeys() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new PaintMyKeysPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class PaintMyKeysPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;

        public PaintMyKeysPane() {

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            label = new JLabel("Press space to change colors", JLabel.CENTER);
            label.setOpaque(true);

            add(label);

            addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

                protected int random() {
                    return (int)Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
                }

                protected Color randomColor() {

                    int r = random();
                    int g = random();
                    int b = random();
                    int a = random();

                    return new Color(r, g, b, a);

                }

                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                        label.setBackground(randomColor());
                        label.setForeground(randomColor());

                    }
                }
            });

            setFocusable(true);
            requestFocusInWindow();        
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, the result of `getKeyText()` is not uniform across browsers, and irrelevant for anything else that the keys that are actually text (letters and numbers).

I think that you should rethink your approach to use `getKeyCode()` instead.

Useful links:

- [This page](http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html) can be useful to test which keyCode is associated to a
  key.
- [This page](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keycodes.htm) provides you a the mapping between key and key
  codes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the getKeyText() method returns words instead of most symbols (e.g. the code for "." produces "PERIOD"). Instead of having " . " and suchlike in your names array, use " PERIOD " and " SPACE ".

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Event/GetKeyText.htm) is the code for the getKeyText() method, it shows exactly which characters will return the key's name.